# Instantiate dynamically buttons on vertical layout group

Tags: unity-game-engine, layout, gameobject

I have the following hierarchy:

[image]

I want to instantiate dinamically `Game Button` into that Button Layout and make them look good.

I'm doing something like this:

```
public GameObject questionButton;

public void nextRound(){

    foreach (Question elem in questionList)
    {
        GameObject child = Instantiate(questionButton);
        child.transform.SetParent(questionButton.transform,false);
        child.GetComponent<Text>().text = elem.answer;
    }
}
```

But does not seem to work properly, it doens't get ordener with the layout:

[image]

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:        `child.transform.SetParent(questionButton.transform,false);`
Should be changed as you are setting the parent as the questionButton. You should be setting it as the layout group. So instead:

```
public GameObject layoutGroup;
...
child.transform.SetParent(layoutGroup.transform,false);
```